# AWS - How to limit Amazon S3 access to a VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I would like to create a policy and attach it to the user, which will only allow them to access to Amazon S3 from an EC2 instance that is on specific VPC. Tried below logic, but, it is not allowing user to access Amazon S3 even the EC2 instance is running on vpc-35test12.

Is there a way to block user from accessing Amazon S3 but allow them only from specific vpc or subnet ?

```
  {
    "Effect": "Allow",
     "NotAction": [
        "iam:*",
        "organizations:*",
        "account:*",
        "s3:*"
        ],
         "Resource": "*"
        },
    {
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": "s3:*",
    "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*",
    "Condition": {
        "StringLike": {
            "aws:SourceVpc": "vpc-35test12"
        }
    }
```

Comment: It is unclear for me how does the user wants to access the S3 from the subnet. If you just simply SSH into an EC2 instance in a subnet, it does not mean that the EC2 instance will have the roles and permissions of the user.

Comment: One solution to this problem would be to create a role for the EC2 instance and create an S3 policy which allows actions from the vpc only from that specific role.

Comment: @ErvinSzilagyi thanks for the feedback, can we block access to s3 from ec2 where ec2 instance is running on specific subnet or vpc ?

Comment: yes, a policy can have an explicit deny,  you just have use `"Effect": "Deny"` with a specific condition in your statement.

Comment: @Prime What do you mean by "attach it to the user"? When a user logs into an Amazon EC2 instance, they are connecting as a user in the Operating System, **not as an IAM User**. Therefore, there is no relationship between an IAM User and the 'user' of an EC2 instance. Would you be willing to lock-down the entire EC2 instance regardless of _who_ is using the instance (including any apps running on that instance)?

Comment: Why not allow the user to access the ec2 and then allow that ec2 instance to access the s3 bucket? Two separate policies,  for two separate principals.

Answer (score 3):

The condition `aws:SourceVpc` works when you have a VPC endpoint for s3. because all the traffic to S3 goes through the public internet only even if the request is originated from the VPC. If you want the VPC to access the S3 privately via internal amazon network (without going through public internet), You will need to create a VPC endpoint for s3 and then use the `aws:SourceVpc` condition to restrict access only to the VPC.

If you just want to allow access to S3 from an EC2 instance, As @Ervin suggested:

- Block public access on S3
- Associate an IAM role to the EC2 instance
- assign an IAM policy to the Role allowing access to S3

Answer (score 0):

I think you are better off creating a specific IAM role and assign it to the instances you want to allow accessing the S3 bucket. After that block all other access to the bucket with an explicit `Deny` for `"Principal" : "*"`  and `aws:userId` or `aws:PrincipalArn`. Here an example policy

```
{
  "Sid":"ItIsOkToDoThis",
  "Effect":"Deny",
  "Action":"*",
  "Principal":"*",
  "Resource":[
    "arn:aws:s3:::ACCESSIBLE_S3_BUCKET/*",
    "arn:aws:s3:::ACCESSIBLE_S3_BUCKET"
  ],
  "Condition": {
  "StringNotLike": {
    "aws:userId": [
    "UNIQUE_ROLE_ID:*"
    ]
  }
 }
}
```

Have a look at this article for more details https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-i-locked-the-whole-company-out-of-an-amazon-s3-bucket-1781de51e4be

Best,
Stefan